# Can I CSS style the contents of an HTML 5 Object tag?

Tags: jquery, object, calendar

For example I am trying to style a google calendar that I want to embed on my site. I use the following Object tag to get around the default iFrame one:

```
<object data="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTz=0&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=2&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;ctz=America%2FNew_York" style="border-width:0" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
    <embed src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTz=0&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=2&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;ctz=America%2FNew_York" style="border-width:0" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> </embed>
    Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.
</object>
```

I have exhausted my research on Google Calendar styling and all the ideas around php, jQuery don't seem to help.

I figured if I could just get the calendar code to be rendered on my site, then use jQuery at the end of my html page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("object .st-bg-today").css({"background":"red"});
});
```

Then the styling might have an effect but I think my theory is flawed.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: how about you try it and see if it works

Comment: Not completely related and certainly not solving your problem but if you want an easier way out you might want to take a look at the following component. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/ I thought it has Google Calendar Intergration.

Comment: @depperm Ok, I forgot to mention that I tried that (obvs) but it didn't work which is why I was asking for help around my "flawed" solution.

Comment: @Wouter125 Yes I saw that in my research. I was hoping for a more elegant and easier solution but at very least, I'll probably fall back on FullCalendar. Thanks for the suggestion.